# Spynner or ghost - How to press a javascript generated button with no id or name (Python)

Tags: python, spynner, ghost.py

How do I get ghost or spynner to press a button without a name or an ID? I have been playing around with ghost and spynner the last couple of days and I just cant get it to work with these two specific sites:

http://freerice.com/#/english-vocabulary/1428 - I want to press an answer.

example:

```
<a href="/" class="answer-item" rel="0">choose</a>
```

http://www.travian.co.uk/#register - I want to press the register button at the buttom (I even tryed the firing the submit from ghost)

example:

```
<div class="bigButtonText play white bold">
                        register
                </div>
```

Is there any way to do this, using eighter ghost, spynner or even pyQt's webkit? It needs to be headless (so selenium and IE's DOM aren't really options).